# Export data from SQL asp.net page to excel truncates data on < character

Tags: sql, asp.net, excel, special-characters, truncate

We have been successfully exporting data from an asp.net system into an excel file.  However we have just come across one issue.  If the data being exported has a "<" (less than) operator within its text, excel truncates the text at that sign.

**For example**, without the single quotes '' around the less than sign(had to put them in here to display the sign):

If the text we were exporting read 
"**The cost of the project was '<'$5,000 and the benefit far outweighed the cost**"

the only part that would be imported into excel would be 
"**The cost of the project was** "

However, when we view the exact same field that we are exporting within the asp.net system itself, we see the whole line of text 
"**The cost of the project was '<'$5,000 and the benefit far outweighed the cost**"

Does anyone have any ideas on how to export the whole line of text (ie: be able to display the special characters) without having excel truncate the text?

Code Behind to setup excel file

```
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel ";
                Response.AddHeader("content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" +
                    SessionInfo.CurrentComplete + RepType + ".xls");
                Response.Write(@"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"">");
                Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
```

Code behind to setup excel fields

```
                        switch (defrow["DataType"].ToString())
                        {
                            case "image":
                                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgPS = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                                imgPS.ImageUrl = datarow[defrow["ColumnName"].ToString()].ToString();
                                imgPS.Height = 15;
                                imgPS.Width = 15;
                                tCell.Controls.Add(imgPS);
                                tCell.HorizontalAlign = System.Web.UI.WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center;
                                break;
                            case "date":
                                convertedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datarow[defrow["ColumnName"].ToString()].ToString());
                                tCell.Text = convertedDate.ToString("d MMM yyyy");
                                break;
                            case "comment":
                                tCell.Text = datarow[defrow["ColumnName"].ToString()].ToString();
                                tCell.Width = 300;
                                break;
                            case "longtext":
                                tCell.Text = RemoveHtmlTag(datarow[defrow["ColumnName"].ToString()].ToString()); 
                                tCell.Width = 500;
                                break;
                            case "shorttext":
                                tCell.Text = datarow[defrow["ColumnName"].ToString()].ToString();
                                tCell.Width = 250;
                                break;
                            default:
                                tCell.Text = datarow[defrow["ColumnName"].ToString()].ToString();
                                break;
                        }
```

SQL Query used to get the data to display information within the main table used within the asp.net system itself and for the main export shown here.

```
        string sql = "SELECT * " + rights +
                     "from table_information " + condition + sortorder;
```

All ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are writing an HTML response to the browser - that cannot contain any unescaped `<` in element content, since the browser sees that as the start of an element tag.  So you need to escape your `<` as `&lt;`

Answer (score 0):

1. If your text contains single/double quotes, you'd need to enclose each quotation mark in double quotes. It will, then, preserve the double quotes as well.

Try changing the text from

```
"The cost of the project was '<'$5,000 and the benefit far outweighed the cost"
```

to

```
"The cost of the project was "'<"'$5,000 and the benefit far outweighed the cost"
```

2. Also, there's no need of single quotes as such. Could you also try replacing, through your code, the text from -

```
"The cost of the project was '<'$5,000 and the benefit far outweighed the cost"
```

to

```
"The cost of the project was &lt;$5,000 and the benefit far outweighed the cost"
```